How to homogenize contrast in GEE + Google Colab ImageCollection
I'm working in Google Colab + GEE on an ROI that is contained in 4 Landsat 9 scenes. I did an ImageCollection search based on the boundaries of the ROI and filtering by cloud cover:
l9_cococi = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LC09/C02/T1_L2").filterBounds(ee_cococi).filterMetadata('CLOUD_COVER', 'less_than', 10).map(l9_remove_cloud)

I defined a function to use the 'clear' pixels of the QA_PIXEL band:
def l9_remove_cloud(img):
  return img.updateMask(img.select('QA_PIXEL').eq(21824))

Then I applied an mean filter:
l9_cococi = l9_cococi.mean()

Finally, I clipped the data to the ROI. However, the result showed that there was no homogenization of the scenes used. It is possible to see variations in contrast due to the overlapping of the scenes used.
Has anyone seen a contrast homogenization resource for a result like this? Perhaps making a mosaic of all the scenes (after the mean reduction filter) and using one of them as a reference? Any ideas?
Link for code: 1


Before dealing the issue of striping, I would suggest two things:

Apply the Landsat Collection 2 scale factors. You have an example in the catalog.

It's often a good idea to use median instead of mean when you reduce your image collection, as it will be less sensitive to any haze and clouds left by your cloud masking.


The stripes you're seeing are due to the BRDF effect. With some effort, you can compensate for that somewhat. I don't have the Python code for it at hand, but here's how it would look in JavaScript.
var ee_cococi = Map.getBounds(true)

var l9_cococi = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LC09/C02/T1_L2")
  .filterBounds(ee_cococi)
  .filterMetadata('CLOUD_COVER', 'less_than', 10)
  .map(applyScaleFactors)
  .map(l9_remove_cloud)
  
var uncorrectedMean = l9_cococi.mean()
var uncorrectedMedian = l9_cococi.median()
var correctedMedian = l9_cococi
  .map(applyBRDFCorrection)
  .median()  

var visParams = {'bands': 'red,green,blue', 'min': 0, 'max': 2000}  
Map.addLayer(uncorrectedMean,  visParams, 'uncorrectedMean')
Map.addLayer(uncorrectedMedian,  visParams, 'uncorrectedMedian')
Map.addLayer(correctedMedian,  visParams, 'correctedMedian')


function applyScaleFactors(image) {
  var opticalBands = image.select('SR_B.').multiply(0.0000275).add(-0.2)
  var thermalBands = image.select('ST_B.*').multiply(0.00341802).add(149.0)
  return image
    .addBands(opticalBands, null, true)
    .addBands(thermalBands, null, true)
    .multiply(10000)
    .uint16()
    .copyProperties(image, image.propertyNames())
}

function l9_remove_cloud(img) {
  var qa = img.select('QA_PIXEL')
  var clear = bitwiseExtract(qa, 6)
  var water = bitwiseExtract(qa, 7)
  return img
    .updateMask(clear.or(water)) 
    .select(
      ['SR_B2', 'SR_B3', 'SR_B4', 'SR_B5', 'SR_B6', 'SR_B7'],
      ['blue', 'green', 'red', 'nir', 'swir1', 'swir2']
    )
}

function bitwiseExtract(value, fromBit, toBit) {
  if (toBit === undefined)
    toBit = fromBit
  var maskSize = ee.Number(1).add(toBit).subtract(fromBit)
  var mask = ee.Number(1).leftShift(maskSize).subtract(1)
  return value.rightShift(fromBit).bitwiseAnd(mask)
}

function applyBRDFCorrection(image) {
  return correct(image).uint16()

  function correct(image) {
    var viewAngles = getViewAngles(image)
    var viewAz = viewAngles.viewAz
    var viewZen = viewAngles.viewZen
    var sunAngles = getSunAngles(image.date())
    var sunAz = sunAngles.sunAz
    var sunZen = sunAngles.sunZen
    var sunZenOut = getSunZenOut(image.geometry())
    var relativeSunViewAz = sunAz.subtract(viewAz)
    var kvol = rossThick(sunZen, viewZen, relativeSunViewAz)
    var kvol0 = rossThick(sunZenOut, 0, 0)
    var kgeo = liThin(sunZen, viewZen, relativeSunViewAz)
    var kgeo0 = liThin(sunZenOut, 0, 0)
    return image.addBands(
      adjustBands(image, kvol, kvol0, kgeo, kgeo0),
      null, true
    )
  }

  function getViewAngles(image) {
    var maxZenith = 7.5
    function findCorners(track) {
      var bounds = ee.List(track.bounds().coordinates().get(0))
      var coords = ee.List(track.coordinates().get(0))
      var xs = coords.map(x)
      var ys = coords.map(y)

      function findCorner(targetValue, values, otherTargetValue, otherValues) {
        var featureCollection = ee.FeatureCollection(
          coords.zip(values).zip(otherValues).map(function(element) {
            element = ee.List(element)
            var coord = ee.List(element.get(0)).get(0)
            var value = ee.Number(ee.List(element.get(0)).get(1))
            var otherValue = ee.Number(element.get(1))
            return ee.Feature(null, {
              coord: coord,
              value: value,
              otherValue: otherValue,
              diff: value.subtract(targetValue).abs().add(otherValue.subtract(otherTargetValue).abs())
            })
          })
        )
        return featureCollection
          .reduceColumns(ee.Reducer.min(2), ['diff', 'coord'])
          .get('min1')
      }

      var lowerLeft = findCorner(x(bounds.get(0)), xs, y(bounds.get(0)), ys)
      var lowerRight = findCorner(y(bounds.get(1)), ys, x(bounds.get(1)), xs)
      var upperRight = findCorner(x(bounds.get(2)), xs, y(bounds.get(2)), ys)
      var upperLeft = findCorner(y(bounds.get(3)), ys, x(bounds.get(3)), xs)
      return {
        upperLeft: upperLeft,
        upperRight: upperRight,
        lowerRight: lowerRight,
        lowerLeft: lowerLeft
      }
    }

    function getViewAz(corners) {
      var upperCenter = pointBetween(corners.upperLeft, corners.upperRight)
      var lowerCenter = pointBetween(corners.lowerLeft, corners.lowerRight)
      var slope = slopeBetween(lowerCenter, upperCenter)
      var slopePerp = ee.Number(-1).divide(slope)
      return expr('PI / 2 - atan(slopePerp)', {
        slopePerp: slopePerp,
        PI: Math.PI
      })
    }

    function getViewZen(corners, maxZenith) {
      var maxDistanceToSceneEdge = 1000000
      var leftLine = toLine(corners.upperLeft, corners.lowerLeft)
      var rightLine = toLine(corners.upperRight, corners.lowerRight)
      var leftDistance = ee.FeatureCollection(leftLine).distance(maxDistanceToSceneEdge)
      var rightDistance = ee.FeatureCollection(rightLine).distance(maxDistanceToSceneEdge)
      return toRadians(expr(
        '(rightDistance * maxZenith * 2) / (rightDistance + leftDistance) - maxZenith', {
          leftDistance: leftDistance,
          rightDistance: rightDistance,
          maxZenith: maxZenith
        }
      ))
    }

    var corners = findCorners(image.geometry())
    var viewAz = getViewAz(corners)
    var viewZen = getViewZen(corners, maxZenith)
    return {
      viewAz: viewAz,
      viewZen: viewZen
    }
  }

  function getSunAngles(date) {
    // Ported from http://pythonfmask.org/en/latest/_modules/fmask/landsatangles.html
    var longDeg = ee.Image.pixelLonLat().select('longitude')
    var latRad = toRadians(ee.Image.pixelLonLat().select('latitude'))
    var jdp = ee.Image(ee.Number(date.getFraction('year')).float()).float()
    var jdpr = expr('jdp * 2 * PI', {
      jdp: jdp,
      PI: Math.PI
    }) // Julian Date Proportion in Radians
    var hourGMT = date.getRelative('second', 'day').divide(3600)
    var meanSolarTime = expr('hourGMT + longDeg / 15', {
      hourGMT: hourGMT,
      longDeg: longDeg
    })
    var localSolarDiff = expr(
      '(0.000075 + 0.001868 * cos(jdpr) - 0.032077 * sin(jdpr) ' +
      '- 0.014615 * cos(2 * jdpr) - 0.040849 * sin(2 * jdpr)) ' +
      '* 12 * 60 / PI', {
        jdpr: jdpr,
        PI: Math.PI
      }
    )
    var trueSolarTime = expr('meanSolarTime + localSolarDiff / 60 - 12', {
      meanSolarTime: meanSolarTime,
      localSolarDiff: localSolarDiff
    })
    var angleHour = toRadians(expr('trueSolarTime * 15', {
      trueSolarTime: trueSolarTime
    }))
    var delta = expr(
      '0.006918 - 0.399912 * cos(jdpr) + 0.070257 * sin(jdpr) - 0.006758 * cos(2 * jdpr) ' +
      '+ 0.000907 * sin(2 * jdpr) - 0.002697 * cos(3 * jdpr) + 0.001480 * sin(3 * jdpr)', {
        jdpr: jdpr
      }
    )
    var cosSunZen = expr('sin(latRad) * sin(delta) + cos(latRad) * cos(delta) * cos(angleHour)', {
      latRad: latRad,
      delta: delta,
      angleHour: angleHour
    })
    var sunZen = expr('acos(cosSunZen)', {
      cosSunZen: cosSunZen
    })
    var sinSunAzSW = expr('cos(delta) * sin(angleHour) / sin(sunZen)', {
      delta: delta,
      angleHour: angleHour,
      sunZen: sunZen
    }).clamp(-1, 1)
    var cosSunAzSW = expr('(-cos(latRad) * sin(delta) + sin(latRad) * cos(delta) * cos(angleHour)) / sin(sunZen)', {
      latRad: latRad,
      delta: delta,
      angleHour: angleHour,
      sunZen: sunZen
    })

    var sunAzSW = expr('asin(sinSunAzSW)', {
      sinSunAzSW: sinSunAzSW
    })
    sunAzSW = sunAzSW.where(
      expr('cosSunAzSW <= 0', {
        cosSunAzSW: cosSunAzSW
      }),
      expr('PI - sunAzSW', {
        sunAzSW: sunAzSW,
        PI: Math.PI
      })
    )
    sunAzSW = sunAzSW.where(
      expr('cosSunAzSW > 0 and sinSunAzSW <= 0', {
        cosSunAzSW: cosSunAzSW,
        sinSunAzSW: sinSunAzSW
      }),
      expr('2 * PI + sunAzSW', {
        sunAzSW: sunAzSW,
        PI: Math.PI
      })
    )

    var uncorrectedSunAz = expr('sunAzSW + PI', {
      sunAzSW: sunAzSW,
      PI: Math.PI
    })
    var sunAz = uncorrectedSunAz
      .where(
        expr('uncorrectedSunAz > 2 * PI', {
          uncorrectedSunAz: uncorrectedSunAz,
          PI: Math.PI
        }),
        expr('uncorrectedSunAz - 2 * PI', {
          uncorrectedSunAz: uncorrectedSunAz,
          PI: Math.PI
        })
      )

    return {
      sunAz: sunAz,
      sunZen: sunZen
    }
  }

  function getSunZenOut(geometry) {
    // https://nex.nasa.gov/nex/static/media/publication/HLS.v1.0.UserGuide.pdf
    var centerLat = toRadians(ee.Number(geometry.centroid(30).coordinates().get(0)).float())
    return toRadians(
      expr(
        '31.0076 ' +
        '- 0.1272 * centerLat ' +
        '+ 0.01187 * pow(centerLat, 2) ' +
        '+ 2.40E-05 * pow(centerLat, 3) ' +
        '- 9.48E-07 * pow(centerLat, 4) ' +
        '- 1.95E-09 * pow(centerLat, 5) ' +
        '+ 6.15E-11 * pow(centerLat, 6)', {
          centerLat: centerLat
        })
    )
  }

  function rossThick(sunZen, viewZen, relativeSunViewAz) {
    var cosPhaseAngle = getCosPhaseAngle(sunZen, viewZen, relativeSunViewAz)
    var phaseAngle = expr('acos(cosPhaseAngle)', {
      cosPhaseAngle: cosPhaseAngle
    })
    return expr(
      '((PI / 2 - phaseAngle) * cosPhaseAngle + sin(phaseAngle)) / (cos(sunZen) + cos(viewZen)) - PI / 4', {
        phaseAngle: phaseAngle,
        cosPhaseAngle: cosPhaseAngle,
        sunZen: sunZen,
        viewZen: viewZen,
        PI: Math.PI
      }
    )
  }

  function liThin(sunZen, viewZen, relativeSunViewAz) {
    // From https://modis.gsfc.nasa.gov/data/atbd/atbd_mod09.pdf
    var sunZenPrime = getAnglePrime(sunZen)
    var viewZenPrime = getAnglePrime(viewZen)
    var cosPhaseAnglePrime = getCosPhaseAngle(sunZenPrime, viewZenPrime, relativeSunViewAz)
    var distance = expr(
      'sqrt(pow(tan(sunZenPrime), 2) + pow(tan(viewZenPrime), 2) ' +
      '- 2 * tan(sunZenPrime) * tan(viewZenPrime) * cos(relativeSunViewAz))', {
        sunZenPrime: sunZenPrime,
        viewZenPrime: viewZenPrime,
        relativeSunViewAz: relativeSunViewAz,
        h_b_ratio: 2
      })
    var temp = expr('1/cos(sunZenPrime) + 1/cos(viewZenPrime)', {
      sunZenPrime: sunZenPrime,
      viewZenPrime: viewZenPrime
    })
    var cosT = expr(
      'h_b_ratio * sqrt(pow(distance, 2) + pow(tan(sunZenPrime) * tan(viewZenPrime) * sin(relativeSunViewAz), 2)) / temp', {
        distance: distance,
        sunZenPrime: sunZenPrime,
        viewZenPrime: viewZenPrime,
        relativeSunViewAz: relativeSunViewAz,
        temp: temp,
        h_b_ratio: 2
      }
    ).clamp(-1, 1)
    var t = expr('acos(cosT)', {
      cosT: cosT
    })
    var overlap = expr('(1 / PI) * (t - sin(t) * cosT) * (temp)', {
      t: t,
      cosT: cosT,
      temp: temp,
      PI: Math.PI
    }).min(0)
    return expr(
      'overlap - temp + (1 / 2) * (1 + cos(cosPhaseAnglePrime)) * (1/cos(sunZenPrime)) * (1/cos(viewZenPrime))', {
        overlap: overlap,
        temp: temp,
        cosPhaseAnglePrime: cosPhaseAnglePrime,
        sunZenPrime: sunZenPrime,
        viewZenPrime: viewZenPrime
      }
    )
  }

  function getAnglePrime(angle) {
    var tanAnglePrime = expr('b_r_ratio * tan(angle)', {
      'b_r_ratio': 1,
      angle: angle
    }).max(0)
    return expr('atan(tanAnglePrime)', {
      tanAnglePrime: tanAnglePrime
    })
  }

  function getCosPhaseAngle(sunZen, viewZen, relativeSunViewAz) {
    return expr(
      'cos(sunZen) * cos(viewZen) + sin(sunZen) * sin(viewZen) * cos(relativeSunViewAz)', {
        sunZen: sunZen,
        viewZen: viewZen,
        relativeSunViewAz: relativeSunViewAz
      }
    ).clamp(-1, 1)
  }

  function adjustBands(image, kvol, kvol0, kgeo, kgeo0) {
    var COEFFICIENTS = {
      'blue': {fiso: 0.0774, fgeo: 0.0079, fvol: 0.0372},
      'green': {fiso: 0.1306, fgeo: 0.0178, fvol: 0.0580},
      'red': {fiso: 0.1690, fgeo: 0.0227, fvol: 0.0574},
      'nir': {fiso: 0.3093, fgeo: 0.0330, fvol: 0.1535},
      'swir1': {fiso: 0.3430, fgeo: 0.0453, fvol: 0.1154},
      'swir2': {fiso: 0.2658, fgeo: 0.0387, fvol: 0.0639}
    }

    return ee.Image(
      Object.keys(COEFFICIENTS).map(function(bandName) {
        var coefficients = COEFFICIENTS[bandName]
        return applyCFactor(
          image.select(bandName),
          kvol,
          kvol0,
          kgeo,
          kgeo0,
          coefficients
        )
      })
    )
  }

  function applyCFactor(band, kvol, kvol0, kgeo, kgeo0, coefficients) {
    var brdf = getBrdf(kvol, kgeo, coefficients)
    var brdf0 = getBrdf(kvol0, kgeo0, coefficients)
    return expr('band * brdf0 / brdf', {
      band: band,
      brdf: brdf,
      brdf0: brdf0
    })
  }

  function getBrdf(kvol, kgeo, coefficients) {
    return expr('fiso + 3 * fvol * kvol + fgeo * kgeo', {
      fiso: coefficients.fiso,
      fgeo: coefficients.fgeo,
      fvol: coefficients.fvol,
      kvol: kvol,
      kgeo: kgeo
    })
  }

  function expr(expression, map) {
    return ee.Image().expression(expression, map)
  }

  function x(point) {
    return ee.Number(ee.List(point).get(0))
  }

  function y(point) {
    return ee.Number(ee.List(point).get(1))
  }

  function pointBetween(pointA, pointB) {
    return ee.Geometry.LineString([pointA, pointB]).centroid().coordinates()
  }

  function slopeBetween(pointA, pointB) {
    return ((y(pointA)).subtract(y(pointB))).divide((x(pointA)).subtract(x(pointB)))
  }

  function toLine(pointA, pointB) {
    return ee.Geometry.LineString([pointA, pointB])
  }

  function toRadians(image) {
    return image.multiply(Math.PI).divide(180)
  }
}

https://code.earthengine.google.com/164fe92971c02c340a756eea0d4925a3
